# Access Vista folders/disk when booted to XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista

I need to recover some user files from a Vista drive that is failing using a Windows XP Pro machine.  I install the drive as a second drive on the XP machine and can see the folders and files but all I get is Access denied when I try to access the file/folders.  Any help?

Answer (score 5):

[How to take ownership of a file or a folder in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421)

Comment: Assuming you are an administrator on the XP machine (maybe superuser or others), you need to first take ownership of the files. Take ownership of the topmost folders and check the box to propagate the change to all child items. 
Then you have access.  
The article Molly linked to describes it perfectly.